# Find unique time from log file , linux grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have entries like

```
[NGS|00219|17-10-2012 19:05:43:977|INFO]
```

in my log file , how can find the unique time values (excluding milli second) in this log file using `grep` or other linux shell tools

Comment: What do you mean by distinct time? Do you want all the logs where the timestamp (excluding millisecond) is unique?

Comment: @sampson-chen yes unique time excluding the millisecond information ..

Comment: Does "time" include the date?

Comment: @jordanm only time date is not required ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to print the unique times:

```
awk '!a[substr($2,0,8)]++ { print substr($2,0,8) }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways, of course -- how about using `cut`, `sed`, and `uniq`:

```
 cut -d' ' -f2 logfile | sed -e 's/:[^:]*$//' | uniq
```

(Take only the stuff after the space, remove everything from the last colon to the end, and then eliminate duplicates.)

Or, just using `sed` and `uniq`:

```
 sed -e 's/.*\ \(.*\):[^:]*$/\1/' logfile | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

This script gives you all the unique timestamps (time only; excludes date. all duplicate timestamps are ignored):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'[: ]' '{print $2 ":" $3 ":" $4}' | sort | uniq -u
```

The use of sort is optional (since I assume the logs are in chronological order)

If you want the entire lines that these timestamps are found in, let me know.

Comment: `awk` can get unique elements. If `gawk` is available, you can easily do the sorting as well, without needing 3 processes.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks =) I'm looking at your solution now

Comment: My solution may not be exactly what he wanted. I went under the assumption of a unique date *and* time, but the logic is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple in awk

```
awk -F'|' '{  
              split($3, a, / /);
              sub(/:[[:digit:]]+$/, "", a[2]); 
              arr[a[2]] = 1; 
           } END { 
              for (i in arr) 
                 print i 
           }' file.log
```

You can use the `sub()` function to remove miliseconds and then add the value as a key to an array. Since array keys are unique, this will remove any duplicates. After processing, the END block iterates over the keys and prints them.

Answer updated to exclude the date. This is done by using split() on the timestamp to remove the date portion.

Comment: Not getting any output on my environment after your last edit, how about your side?

Comment: @sampson-chen I messed up the edit, thanks for pointing it out. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant:

```
awk '{print $2}' log.txt | cut -c 1-8 | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to egrep command, you can use grep as follows:

grep -o -E '[[:digit:]]+[:][[:digit:]]+[:][[:digit:]]+' NGS.log|uniq

Answer (score 0):

Myself found a good answer

```
egrep -o '[[:digit:]]+[:][[:digit:]]+[:][[:digit:]]+' NGS.log | uniq
```

Comment: There is always more than one way to do it!